# Introductions and Conclusions - treating as normal chapters without numbers

Tags: sectioning, chapters, classicthesis

Pardon the novice asking what is probably quite a silly question - I have already Googled without much success...

I note that LaTeX allows you to stop a chapter from being numbered by inserting an asterisk into the code ie. `\chapter*`

What is the equivalent code for classicthesis, and is it possible to have my introduction treated in all other respects like the other chapters in terms of layout? Essentially, I'd like to have my introduction, a set of numbered chapters, then an unnumbered conclusion and my references.

Answer (score 3):

The `classicthesis` style uses `titlesec` to format its titles. You can use the method described there to simply change the section number depth for the chapter(s) you want to be unnumbered. Note that this solution assumes that there are no sections to the unnumbered chapters (or if there are, you introduce them with `\section*`.)

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
    \myChapter{Unnumbered Introduction}

    \lipsum[1]

    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    \lipsum[1]

    \myChapter{Test Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{A Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \myChapter{Test Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{A Section}
    \lipsum[1]


   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
    \myChapter{Unnumbered conclusion}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The Koma-script classes provide `\addchap`; so `\addchap{Introduction}` should be sufficient.

Comment: @egreg `\addchap` by itself won't quite work, since it will not apply the correct formatting for the TOC entry.