# Making Conclusion, Bibliography and Table of index without chapter Number with inclusion in Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, books

I want the table of contents in my thesis to look like this:
[Contents First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiTwY.png),
[Contents Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pljG3.png)

%*The images are not included here visually, purposefully otherwise the question will become too long*.

**Note** that everything before the **Introduction** appears before the table of contents.

Also, the Bibliography, table of indexes, and conclusion should not appear with chapter number in the actual thesis.

I have gone through the following answers: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133258), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243821), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8458) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286880),
but found no help.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption, bm, float, color}
%\usepackage[ inner =1.5in , outer =1in ]{ geometry }
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}


\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \thechapter\nobreakspace%\quad
        \fi
        #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}


\@ifundefined{chapter}%
{}%
{\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{chapter} < 1}%
        {\markboth{#1}{}}%
        {\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
}}


\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %% thin line under header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %% no line under header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}                            %% Clear all fields.
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\thepage}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{0.3cm}
            \Huge
            \textbf{NAME OF THE TOPIC}\\
            \vspace{1cm}
            \Large \textbf{A THESIS}\\
            \vspace{0.3cm}
            \large \emph{submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements}\\
            \emph{for the award of the  degree of}\\
            \vspace{0.7cm}
            \Large \textbf{NAME OF THE DEGREE}\\
            \vspace*{0.3cm}
            \large \emph{in}\\
            \vspace*{0.3cm}
            \Large \textbf{SUBJECT}\\
            \vspace*{0.3cm}
            \large \emph{by}\\
            \vspace*{0.3cm}
            \Large \textbf{STUDENT NAME}\\\vspace{0.3cm} \textbf{ID}\\
            \vspace*{0.5cm}
            \begin{center}      
                \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{_Logo.jpeg}
            \end{center}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            
            \Large
            \textbf{DEPARTMENT OF SUBJECT}\\
            \textbf{UNIVERSITY NAME}\\\textbf{NAME}\\
            \textbf{LOCATION}\\
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            
            \textbf{YEAR OF SUBMISSION}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge\textbf{CERTIFICATE}
\end{center}
    \vspace*{0.7cm}
    \paragraph*{}This is to certify that student name, degree name student in Department of subject, has completed bonafied work on the thesis entitled '\textbf{name of the project}' under our supervision and guidance.\\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{flushleft}
            year\\ student
        \end{flushleft}
        \columnbreak
        %\setlength{\columnsep}{*}
        \begin{flushleft}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}  advisor 1   
        \end{flushleft}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{flushleft}
            \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}  Dr. advisor 2
        \end{flushleft}
        %\setlength{\coulmnsep}{*}
    \end{multicols} 
\vspace*{5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{center}
        Committee Member
    \end{center}
    %\vspace*{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
    \end{center}
    \columnbreak
    \begin{center}
        Signature
    \end{center}
    %\vspace*{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        Date
    \end{center}
    %\vspace*{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        %\vspace*{0.5cm}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
    \end{center}
\end{multicols}
\newpage
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead{\thepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{ACADEMIC INTEGRITY AND COPYRIGHT DISCLAIMER}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{center}
        year \\ institution
    \end{center}
    \columnbreak
    \null
    \columnbreak
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\columnwidth}{0.1pt}
        student
    \end{center}
\end{multicols}
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{ABSTRACT}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{LIST OF FIGURES}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \huge \textbf{LIST OF TABLES}
\end{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\paragraph*{}\large \lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2cm}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\fancyfoot{}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}%\stepcounter{chapter}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\normalsize
\paragraph*{}\lipsum[2]

\section{Section 1}\lipsum[3]
\section{section 2}\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Further Info}
\lipsum[1]
\section{section 3}\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{}reference 1
\bibitem{}reference 2

\end{thebibliography}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Table of indexes}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Kindly help me. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanking you.

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`} showing, briefly, what you have tried.

Comment: @PeterWilson Done! Can you help now.\? Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your "Conclusion"

```
\chapter*{Conclusion}  % no number
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion} % add it to the ToC
```

and similarly for "Table of Indexes".

I haven't ploughed through all the stuff in your MWE, most of which, for instance the title page and following stuff have nothing to do with your problem, and don't know how you managed to change the output of the `thebibliograpy` environment from its `book` class default, which is as below.

```
% bookbibprob.tex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname} % extra to add it to the ToC
\bibitem{}reference 1
\end{thebibliography}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} % just to get it all on one page
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you very much, sir.